# Deleting a registry subkey in Visual Basic 6

Tags: vb6

I am working on an application that deletes registry subkeys, but I can't seem to find a solution for that problem... I know it is easier to do this with VB.NET but I want to know how to get this done using VB6

What I have tried...

`DeleteRegKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Test`.

Comment: this is your book: http://www.amazon.com/Applemans-Visual-Basic-Programmers-Guide/dp/0672315904

Comment: @JeffOnsager Thanks, but I am not interested in buying one right now.. If you can provide a solution for this here it would be great

Comment: You should post the code you have and a description of what part of the code you are having a problem with.

Comment: @jac I tried using RegKeyDelete method, but I don't know how to use it in order to delete the registry keys...

Answer (score 0):

Take this for what it's worth. I haven't used this in a few years so it has not been tested on Windows 8, and I'm not at all sure about Windows 7 either. I pulled this from a utility class so hopefully I got all the declarations.

```
Private Const KEY_NOTIFY = &H10
Private Const KEY_QUERY_VALUE = &H1
Private Const KEY_CREATE_LINK = &H20
Private Const KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY = &H4
Private Const KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS = &H8
Private Const KEY_EVENT = &H1
Private Const KEY_SET_VALUE = &H2
Private Const KEY_ALL_ACCESS = ((STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL Or KEY_QUERY_VALUE Or KEY_SET_VALUE Or KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY Or KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS Or KEY_NOTIFY Or KEY_CREATE_LINK) And (Not SYNCHRONIZE))
Private Const KEY_READ = ((STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ Or KEY_QUERY_VALUE Or KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS Or KEY_NOTIFY) And (Not SYNCHRONIZE))
Private Const KEY_EXECUTE = ((KEY_READ) And (Not SYNCHRONIZE))
Private Const KEY_WRITE = ((STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE Or KEY_SET_VALUE Or KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY) And (Not SYNCHRONIZE))

Public Enum RegRootKey
    HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT = &H80000000
    HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG = &H80000005
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
    HKEY_DYN_DATA = &H80000006
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
    HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA = &H80000004
    HKEY_USERS = &H80000003
End Enum

Private Declare Function RegCloseKey Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal hKey As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function RegCreateKeyEx Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "RegCreateKeyExA" (ByVal hKey As Long, ByVal lpSubKey As String, ByVal Reserved As Long, ByVal lpClass As String, ByVal dwOptions As Long, ByVal samDesired As Long, ByVal lpSecurityAttributes As Long, phkResult As Long, lpdwDisposition As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function RegDeleteKey Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "RegDeleteKeyA" (ByVal hKey As Long, ByVal lpSubKey As String) As Long
Private Declare Function RegEnumKeyEx Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "RegEnumKeyExA" (ByVal hKey As Long, ByVal dwIndex As Long, ByVal lpName As String, lpcbName As Long, ByVal lpReserved As Long, ByVal lpClass As String, lpcbClass As Long, lpftLastWriteTime As FILETIME) As Long


Public Function DeleteRegKey(ByVal hKeyRoot As RegRootKey, ByVal hKeySubKey As String, ByVal KeyName As String) As Boolean
   Dim lngRst As Long
   Dim hKeyReturn As Long
   Dim hKeyDisposition As Long
   Dim strSubKeys() As String
   Dim lngSubKeyCount As Long
   Dim i As Long

   On Error GoTo errDeleteRegKey

   lngRst = RegOpenKeyEx(hKeyRoot, hKeySubKey, ByVal 0&, KEY_READ + KEY_WRITE, hKeyReturn)

   If lngRst = 0 Then 'we can continue
      ' first need to find and delete sub keys
      lngSubKeyCount = EnumSubKeys(hKeyRoot, hKeySubKey & "\" & KeyName, strSubKeys)
      ' recursively call this function to delete all sub keys
      For i = 0 To lngSubKeyCount - 1
         Call DeleteRegKey(hKeyRoot, hKeySubKey & "\" & KeyName, strSubKeys(i))
      Next i
      ' finally down (up?) to the parent key
      lngRst = RegDeleteKey(hKeyReturn, ByVal KeyName)
      'close the handle
      If hKeyReturn <> 0 Then
         lngRst = RegCloseKey(hKeyReturn)
         hKeyReturn = 0
      End If
   End If

   If lngRst = 0 Then   '0 = success
      DeleteRegKey = True
   Else
      Err.Raise lngRst, App.EXEName, FormatClassError(lngRst)
   End If

   Exit Function

errDeleteRegKey:
   'close the handle
   If hKeyReturn <> 0 Then
      lngRst = RegCloseKey(hKeyReturn)
      hKeyReturn = 0
   End If
   Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source & ":DeleteRegKey", Err.Description

End Function
```

Add this function to a form, module, or class then

```
Call DeleteRegKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software", "Test")
' or
DeleteRegKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software", "Test"
' or
Dim blnRst as Boolean
blnRst = DeleteRegKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software", "Test")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but can you explain how am I suppose to do this if I want to delete a registry key called "Test" for example from "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Test"? Thanks